# JavaScript code is not executed after HTTPWebRequest

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I know similar questions were asked here, but I can't find an answer. 
I have VB code-behind default.aspx:

```
Dim array() As String = {"q3"}

    Dim s As HttpWebRequest
    Dim enc As UTF8Encoding
    Dim postdata As String
    Dim postdatabytes As Byte()

    For index As Integer = 0 To array.Length - 1
        postdata = createDiv(array(index).ToString())
        s = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:61834/HiddenPage.aspx?
            postdata=" & postdata & "&number=" & index)
        enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
        postdatabytes = enc.GetBytes(postdata)
        s.Method = "GET"
        Dim result = s.GetResponse()
        Using reader = New StreamReader(result.GetResponseStream())              
            Response.Write(reader.ReadToEnd())
            End Using
    Next
```

I have another file HP.asxp:

```
  Dim toFrontPostData As String
  Dim toFrontNumber As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
 Handles Me.Load

    toFrontPostData = """" & Request.QueryString("postdata") & """"
    toFrontNumber = Request.QueryString("number")

End Sub
```

Client-side code of HP.aspx:

```
     var $div = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
     $div.attr('id', 'contentDiv' + <%=toFrontNumber %>)
```

But when I analyze the response from HP.aspx I do not see the JS code (above) was executed.
What could be the reason? I know my code is not elegant at all, but it's not about elegance, it's about an issue :) Thanks in advance!

UPD What I get in response:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
          src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <script type="text/javascript">
             var $div = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
             $div.attr('id', 'contentDiv' + 0)
             $div.text(a);
        </script>

    <!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
    <script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
        {"appName":"Unknown","requestId":"18836b8be88f40bcb97c88523575b3bb"}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://localhost:62047/40192b79ee2d47e3ad5a016389383a18/browserLink" 
        async="async"></script>
    <!-- End Browser Link -->

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What does your Javascript look like in the browser? And are there any Javascript errors?

Comment: It should create a div, but it looks like a regular javascript code... No, there are no errors. That's weird

Comment: Can you show us the Javascript code, as it ends up in the browser? Also, what is it conatined in? just a normal `<script>` block?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: The declaration of your `a` variable is not in the output.

Comment: sorry, var a shouldn't be in a code, I have modified the question

Comment: But you are trying to use it, and it's not defined: `$div.text(a);`

Comment: You are right, but it's just supplementary data. The main idea is to create  a div. If I create a div, I'll use it later. That's why I removed the part of code with var a from output

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you then. I pasted that output into a static html file (without the Visual Studio Browser Link block) and it works - the div gets created.

Comment: Anyway, thank you!